# Can you bundle a JavaFX jar as an OS X application?

Tags: macos, jar, javafx

I'm looking for a way to bundle JavaFX applications similarly to the way I can bundle Java applications using Jar Bundler? I really would like to have a custom icon for my program(and the ability to pin it to the Dock). Is there a way to do this now, or do I have to wait for JavaFX to mature in the Java market?

Answer (score 1):

Technically you can since JavaFX is basically a Java program. However, it would take some work to get the environment set up properly for JavaFX. Look at the javafx executable in the SDK to see how JavaFX is launched.

Answer (score 0):

If people would still stumble upon this question: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/self-contained-packaging.htm